# Error while starting chromedriver from java application on raspberry pi

Tags: java, selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver, debian

I want to run my java standalone jar on my raspberry pi (Model 3B+). It depends on seleneium, so it needs chromedriver. I have installed java 14 and also chromedrivers version 95.0.4638.78-rpt6 via

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

now I have installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep chromium
ii  chromium-browser                     95.0.4638.78-rpt6                armhf        Chromium web browser, open-source version of
ii  chromium-browser-l10n                95.0.4638.78-rpt6                all          chromium-browser language packages
ii  chromium-chromedriver                95.0.4638.78-rpt6                armhf        WebDriver driver for the Chromium Browser
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra         95.0.4638.78-rpt6                armhf        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
ii  rpi-chromium-mods                    20220111
```

When I start my application now, I get this log:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG                                                     (file:/home/pi/StreamCrawler.jar) to constructor sun.security.provider.Sun()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.bouncycastle.j                                                    cajce.provider.drbg.DRBG
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflect                                                    ive access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
/usr/bin/chromedriver: 5: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Feb 06, 2022 6:39:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:24:01'
System info: host: 'raspberrypi', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '5.10.92-v7+', java.version: '14'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
        at crawler.RequestCrawler.getPlaylistURL(RequestCrawler.java:48)
        at crawler.StreamCrawler.crawl(StreamCrawler.java:29)
        at crawler.StateChecker.run(StateChecker.java:37)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:11309/status] to be available after 20017 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
        ... 12 more
```

On my windows machine it runs fine. But on windows I am using chromedriver 98, not 95. Now I am not sure what to do as next step.

Option A is an update of the chromedrivers to 98 on my raspberry. But when I am checking out https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/, there is no 98. In https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.80/ I can find a 98 Linux version but how to install that file without extension?

Option B is a java application which runs with chromedrivers 95. Currently I use this selenium version:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

Would it run if I use an older version? And which version do I need?

Is there maybe an other better option? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Within the [*Raspberrypi chromium-browser archive*](https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/) the latest version seems **chromium-browser v95**.

So with the combination of:

- *selenium=3.141.59*
- *chromium-browser=95.0.4638.78*
- *chromedriver=95.0.4638.69*

would be definately good to go.